# Make all internal links relative, or otherwise make a website accessible from multiple domains

Tags: permalinks, links

I'd like to make a WordPress website self-contained. That is, all its internal resources (images, pages, etc.) should be cross-linked independently of the site location.

If I decide to move the website later (e.g. change the domain name), I should be able to do it without *any* changes to the content. This is a very basic requirement, and is not dissimilar to a piece of software that can be relocated to any directory without changes. Any good software allows that.

Furthermore, the website may be accessible from multiple domains simultaneously (say, `foo.com` and `foo.org`) on the same host, and when accessed from one, all its internal resources must be polled from the same domain it was accessed from without redirection.

An obvious way to achieve this is to use *relative* URLs for all internal resources, much like a good program would use relative paths to open its own internal files - or, alternatively, would construct full paths using its *current* location on the fly.

However, I don't see a good way to do it in WordPress. (I must say I'm new to it). It has a setting (`Site Address (URL)`) which sets the root address and which is used to construct all links - and which, to my mind, shouldn't even exist: I don't *know* the site address yet, an it is subject to change at any moment.

This creates even more problems during development. Of course, I develop locally, on `localhost`. All published (or any, really) links then refer explicitly to localhost, e.g.

```
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/foo.jpg">
```

But sometimes I access this computer from another (within LAN) using its real hostname and, obviously, nothing works.

This all could be solved if WordPress could generate links like `src="/wp-content/uploads/foo.jpg">` instead, but I don't see how. I'm puzzled how WP makes basic things so difficult.

Maybe there is another way, like writing a function that would replace all URLs on the fly. I'm a bit lost...

EDIT

The closest question (almost a duplicate) I found is this 10-year-old one: [root-relative links for multiple parked domains](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50512/root-relative-links-for-multiple-parked-domains). I haven't tried the presented solution yet. It appears that it's relatively hard to work around, because WP was foolishly designed with absolute URLs in mind throughout...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter to output of the get\_permalink() function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267131/how-to-filter-to-output-of-the-get-permalink-function)

Comment: Wordpress always saves the full URL. I suggest removing the host name from the links. The question I marked as duplicate will tell you how to do that, and in your filter you will need to replace the schema and host name with a slash `return preg_replace('/^(.*?)\/\/(.*)\//', '/', $url);` You're going to have an issue with caching. I don't know how to force it to store URLs as relative URLs, which IMO it should by default.

Comment: @popnoodles, thanks, I was trying to do something along these lines (my biggest immediate issue is with images, so I've got some success with substituting `wp_get_attachment_url`). This works when adding new images to the page: now WP generates a correct link. But I can't figure out how to change links of the items that were added before (without replacing them anew). It seems that WP just dumbly 'bakes' the links in when they are added, and the way to change them is to do text replacement on the whole page (using some migratory tool perhaps...)

Comment: Ah yes it puts links inside post content when you add media, and it does just bake the link when added. The fastest way to change them all would be using SQL REPLACE, but you could also make them relative on save by altering content that's posted